# Bypass windows login screen with VNC

Tags: security, remote-desktop, vnc

I'm looking for some vnc software or tool that can bypass the windows login screen after a user logs into the vnc server.

For example, I have a user called John on the vnc server, when I authenticate to the server using John's password, the server needs to bypass the login screen (users list) and get directly to John's Desktop.

I don't want to just enable automatic user logon.

Is this possible?, did you understand what I mean? haha.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think VNC does what you're looking for as it's supposed to be a remote console view, as if you're at the desktop, not a remote desktop session. If it's possible to do it would require a very specific server program.

You might have better luck just using RDP. That gives you a logged in session. But it won't give it to the person sitting at the remote end in the chair.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I need vnc because I only want one "desktop session". Thanks for your answer!.

Comment: Depending on the version of Windows, it does limit the number of sessions that can be logged in (and who). For example, if Bob is logged in and you RDP in as Bob, it boots the other session off.

Comment: Yes, but I want only one desktop to be shown for any user connected. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Using [ultravnc](http://uvnc.com) and the ms-logon I system, you can autenticate users avaliable from the machine running the server, and thus bypass the login screen.

Comment: I'm going to try it right now and let you know!

Comment: I tried this, but when I login through vnc (using a valid active directory user), the remote machine still shows me the login screen instead of login to that user directly. :(

Comment: Just realize that I don't know if I'm using ms logon I or II.

Answer (score 0):

According to :

https://www.tightvnc.com/doc/win/TightVNC_for_Windows-Installation_and_Getting_Started.pdf

"TightVNC Server is designed to run in two modes:

• application mode (personal server for a current user);

• service mode (system-wide server running in the background).

In application mode, the server, just like any other desktop software, can be running only during the
current user session and quits on the logout. Each user has his/her personal settings and passwords. "

In order to bypass windows login screen with VNC please run VNC server in application mode from CMD with this command line :

tvnserver.exe [ -run ]

More information on commands can be found here :

https://www.tightvnc.com/doc/win/TightVNC_2.7_for_Windows_Server_Command-Line_Options.pdf